# How to handle login requests to a Node server using PassportJS for Google and Facebook OAUth?

Tags: node.js, flutter, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am using *Passport* solely for redirecting the OAuth requests to Google/Facebook permissions page and generating a JWT token in the success callback. I am explicitly setting `{session: false}` in the routes using `passport.authenticate()`.

The success callback function looks something like:

```
router.get(
  "/auth/facebook/callback",
  passport.authenticate("facebook", {
    failureRedirect: "/api/auth/fail",
    session: false,
  }),
  async (req, res) => {
    const user = { email: req.user?.email };

    res.json({
      status: true,
      message: "User logged in",
      data: { token: jwt.sign(user, sign, { expiresIn: "14d" }) },
    });
  }
);
```

I am using my own authentication middleware which looks like:

```
const authMiddleware = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    if (!req.body.token) {
      return res.json({ status: false, message: "Login required" });
    }

    req.currentUser = jwt.verify(req.body.token, sign);

    next();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("ERROR:" + err);
    return res.json({ status: false, message: "Please login again" });
  }
};
```

Google has a specific way of implementing *Cross-client authentication* similar to this use case mentioned n *Google OAuth 2.0* documentation. However, I could not find something similar for Facebook.

Is there a way to handling the redirect on a Flutter app? Or should I think of a different implementation on the server-side of things? If the latter, what is recommended in this use case?

Comment: It really helps on SO if you are extremely specific with your question and I would limit it to one question to help target your replies.  Quoting code is great but make sure it's the actual code you're using and describe also what is not working for you right now.

Comment: This is the code I'm using. But I can't figure out a way to fetch the final Response object which served to my webview as a JSON.